# Visualizacion pop-up

Tags: html, c#, asp.net, vb.net, vb

estoy teniendo unos problemas a la hora de visualizar un pop-up. Tengo un pop-up que se abre al dar click a un botón con diferentes campos de edición. El problema que tengo es a la hora de cargar todo el programa que el pop-up me desaparece y no se exactamente por que puede ser.

Esta es la parte de HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel1">Edicion de receta</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label>AZUCAR</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtAzucar" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>TEMPERATURA</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTemp" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>VELOCIDAD AGITACIÓN</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtVelAgi" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>SAL</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtSal" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                            <label>TIEMPO(minutos)</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtTiempoMinutos" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>FIN DE PASO</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFinPaso" runat="server" CssClass="form-control">
                                <asp:ListItem>Tiempo</asp:ListItem>
                                <asp:ListItem>Temperatura</asp:ListItem>
                            </asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
      <div class="modal-footer">
         <%--<td>--%>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnRegistrar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary" Width="200px" Text="GUARDAR" OnClick="btnRegistrar_Click" />
                <%--    </td>--%>
                    <%--<td>--%>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%--</td>--%>
                    <%--<td>--%>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnCancelar" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-danger" Width="200px" Text="CANCELAR" OnClick="btnCancelar_Click" />
                   <%-- </td>--%>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Luego en la parte de código tengo lo siguiente:

```
   Public Sub EdicionRecetaDatos()
        Dim var1 = "Azucar"
        Dim var2 = "Temperatura"
        Dim var3 = "VelocidadAgitacion"
        Dim var4 = "SAL"
        Dim var5 = "Tiempo"
        Dim var6 = "FindePaso"
        Dim constr As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("RECETAConnectionString").ConnectionString
        Dim query As String = "select * from " & Module1.Rnom.ToString & "_V" & Module1.verc.ToString

        Using con As New SqlConnection(constr)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand(query)
                Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter()
                    cmd.Connection = con
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd
                    Using ds As New DataSet()
                        sda.Fill(ds)
                        var1 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var1).ToString
                        var2 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var2).ToString
                        var3 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var3).ToString
                        var4 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var4).ToString
                        var5 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var5).ToString
                        var6 = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)(var6).ToString
                        'grupo = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("Grupo").ToString
                        'Config.usuario.Value = Config.Equals[]
                        'Context.Items.Add("usuario", usuario)
                        'Module1.usuario = usuario

                        'GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
                        'GridView1.DataBind()
                        'GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(1)
                        'GridView1.DataBind()

                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

        txtAzucar.Text = var1
        txtTemp.Text = var2
        txtVelAgi.Text = var3
        txtSal.Text = var4
        txtTiempoMinutos.Text = var5

    End Sub
```

A la hora de guardar la edición, tengo un campo que me coge el usuario que esta registrado en ese momento a través de el site master. Veo que al cargar el pop-up se activa tanto el evento de page_load de SiteMaster como de mi otra Page, primero hace el de la Page y luego el del SiteMaster no se si eso tendrá algo que ver.

Si depuro puedo ver que el pop-up esta completamente rellenado y correctamente pero si lo hago sin depurar nunca llego a ver el pop-up

Comment: Creo que desaparece porque Site.Master al acabar la funcion que me genera los datos se vuelve a iniciar.Como puedo evitarlo?

Comment: He probado añadiendo un botón dentro del modal que llame a la funcion, pero sigue pasando lo mismo, al terminar la funcion inicia el site master de nuevo.